# Android snackbar does not show continuously

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I got problem when showing a SnackBar:

I have an Activity with 3 Fragments using ViewPager, each Fragment have a RecyclerView

When data is shown in RecyclerView, I will have a list item, each item have a button, when I click on the button, it will show a snackbar:

When init fragment, i passed the activity view to fragment using

```
myFragment.setParentView(root)
```

I create an Interface for OnClickedListener, so when I click on the button in list item, I use:

```
listener.onClick(position);
```

And show the snackbar from fragment when even is called:

```
Snackbar.make(parentView, "position: " + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
```

But when user clicks button on list item continuously, snackbar will not be displayed

Ex: I have a list with 5 items, when I click on button on each item continuously, snackbar will be shown only 3 or 4 times

I have tried but do not have any solutions, I used the latest support version

Comment: You need to show snack bar  for individual page(Fragment) or show on main Activity.

Comment: @Rohitashvjain that why I passed the activity view to the fragments, but the problem is the snackbar is shown only 4 times when user clicked on 5 items for example

Comment: had you done debug for that, getting click event call back or not on 5th click.

Comment: @Rohitashvjain yes, got 5 clicked events, but shown less than 4 times

Comment: I don't know what code you exactly return, but try one thing  i am suggesting you make global object of snack bar, and than you call method showing snack bar, apply check in this method mSnackBar!=null&& !mSnackBar.isShowing

in else part show snack bar and initialize object accordingly.

initialize snackbar object only once.

Comment: @Rohitashvjain Did it but got the same result, but when i added this code: if (snackbar.isShown()) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        } , everything is ok now, thanks

Comment: yes i said the same, if snack bar is showing please do now show once again if needed than dismiss previous stage than show once again.